# "environment can only contain strings" error while creating a Django CMS project on Windows

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am getting this error when trying to build a project with 
`djangocms -p . mysite`

I have gone through all the answers in StackOverflow but couldn't solve the problem.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC4\Desktop\site14\env\Scripts\djangocms-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('djangocms-installer==0.8.1', 'console_scripts', 'djangocms')()
  File "c:\users\pc4\desktop\site14\env\lib\site-packages\djangocms_installer\main.py", line 41, in execute
    django.setup_database(config_data)
  File "c:\users\pc4\desktop\site14\env\lib\site-packages\djangocms_installer\django\__init__.py", line 404, in setup_database
    env=env
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
TypeError: environment can only contain strings
```

Changing to Linux is not an option.

Comment: Enter the python shell and run this: `import os; os.environ`. I suspect one of your environmental variables is a unicode string.

Comment: Thank you, but still getting the error.

Comment: That wasn't supposed to fix the error, but help you figure out what was causing it. Did anything in `os.environ` look like `u'some text here'`? (i.e., start with `u'`)

Comment: Sorry, didn't find anything.

Comment: What output did you get from `os.environ`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/abFky2Hs too long to comment here. This is the university computer where I am doing research, so there might be some weird stuff.

Comment: I got the same error today on my windows 10 for wagtail cms. I changed virtualenv to python 3.6 and it's working.